# 'ThetaModelResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to create a theta model to forecast time series data, using statsmodels library.

that code is:

```
theta = ThetaModel(d, period = 12)
res_theta = theta.fit()
predictions_test = np.round(np.exp(res_theta.forecast(extra_periods, theta = 2).values))
```

Which gives me predictions over the value of extra_periods (set to 12).

However,I would also like to look at predictions made over the training data and I use the code:

```
predictions_train = res_theta.get_prediction()
```

Which results in:

```
AttributeError: 'ThetaModelResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'
```

Would anyone know how to get predictions for the training set using the theta model on python's statsmodel package? I searched the docs and couldn't find anything to solve my issue

I have been searching the docs for statsmodels and cannot find the information I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late.

With reference to the documentation concerning the `ThetaModelResults` class, you have to use the method `.prediction_intervals()` which will return a dataframe containing the lower and upper confidence values which is the same as the mean_ci_lower and mean_ci_upper from `get_prediction()` method available to other models.

Here the line you need based on your code:

```
pred_df = res_theta.prediction_intervals(12) # 12 is the steps ahead for forecasting
```

Do note that it does not contain the mean values, so just calculate directly from its upper and lower bound values!

I understand your frustration in this issue, Statsmodels's documentation is some what messy, and maybe unfriendly to some. I just started using this library too!

I recommend you try out Darts, a new library for compiling all things forecasting and this includes machine learning solutions as well.